# telegram bot c# webhook and getupdates in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webhooks, telegram-bot

im developing an app in ***C#.net WinForm*** which includes telegram_bot :). telegram bot api offers **getUpdates and webhook** ...since my bot should be responsive to messages i need a method that app could distinguish the last updates which are not responded.

**getupdates** is polling method and gives all updates .... i tried to use infinity loop over the json result bot it seems creepy and hangy.

**webhook** is a method i need which always notifies me about the new coming updates and app can easily distinguish the new updates and can respond ....**BUT** my app is **Winform** not web and webhook needs URL :( ...

could you help me to overcome to this issue......thank you

Comment: You need to establish a method of communication for your app to communicate with the server. One possible way to do it is by standing up a `HttpListener` so the server can reach a registered instance of your app (Webhook), but I am assuming that you app would be reachable from the server which doesn't sound likely.  A more modern approach is to use something like `SignalR` to establish the communication channel from client to server.  See https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b for a sample.

Comment: The above Comment is the SOLUTION. i made a webHost which uses WEBHOOK api for my telegram bot (telegram server => webhost) then i used signalR for forward the notifications to my Desktop client APP (webhost => Desktop APP)................thank you @Roberto Hernandez

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem about two years ago when telegram first introduced the bot api. i could solve it with service base architecture. at first i created web api project and handled or incoming bot requests with simple web hook. then i created another services like:

1. send message to all users.
2. send message to user by mobile number
3. .
4. .

finally i created a win form in order to consume my services. i hope this could solve your problem too.